# Insert large blob into vitess through node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, vitess

I'm using this method to insert a large blob into my mySQL database (Blob size ~40MB) After ~15 seconds it throws a exception or CPU utilisation goes to 100% and remains 100% upto ~25-50 seconds. The whole thing here works with blobs smaller then ~7MB.

I am using node js, [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Comment: Your file size is too large it is better to storing the file in a directory and store location of the file in the db.

Comment: I am using docker containers, so I want to access that blob into another container which is not possible if i'm storing it into file. Also, on restarting container, it is quite possible that I will loose files.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) FLUSH LOGS; then post LAST 400 lines of your error log.
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server blob sizing analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Hi [wilson-hauck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4420649/wilson-hauck), Currently I'm trying it on my development machine which is quad core 256GB SSD with 16GB of RAM.

Comment: @Vikas         Your development machine should be FINE. Any chance you can post additional requested info?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bump the grpc_max message_size for vtgates and vttablets: https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/blob/master/go/vt/grpccommon/options.go#L28-L32. Even otherwise, it should have returned an error.

Comment: Already done, it's working with other languages like JAVA, I tried in JAVA, but not with the node js.

Comment: This isn't something we've seen before. When it hangs, can you look at '/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=1' for the vtgate? It may give us a clue. If the stack trace is too big, you could post it as an issue on github.